# mysql Search data from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

**user**

```
ID  |  Name  |  Class
```

---

**Category**

```
ID  |  user_id  |  cat_id
```

If user inputs data from a text field how do I search data from both tables?

Comment: Take a look at JOIN, LIKE and MySQL wildcards.

Comment: It's maybe possible or not it's depend on what you want exactly as result.
You can use join, subquery or union...

Comment: what u  mean? you need the time of insertion use mysql_insert_id for user_id to table2.

Comment: start writing join in db and them help can be provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from user, category 
WHERE user.id=[text field]  
or category.user_id=[text field]  
or category.cat_id=[text field]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a basic query with joins. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN category c ON c.user_id = u.id 
    WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables together.

```
Select *
from User , Category
where user.id = Category.user_id
```

Basicly you are linking the two together by the based upon the user_id that they both share.  This way you get the information back from both tables.

Here is a link to help you understand the concept. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try it

you need the time of insertion use `mysql_insert_id for user_id` to table2.

In the  selection time use JOIN in  mysql

eg

```
"select * from tb1,tb2 where tb1.ID=tb2.user_id and where tb1.ID='userid' "
```

for a specific user

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT * FROM user
LEFT JOIN category ON category.user_id = user.ID 
WHERE user.Name LIKE '%lorem%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can do like this:

```
SELECT * from user
LEFT JOIN category ON user.id = category.user_id 
WHERE text_field IN (user.id,category.user_id,category.cat_id)
```